# Returning boolean from DB2 using JPQL

Tags: java, sql, db2, jpql

As a part of a compound JPQL query I am using a subselect

```
(select count(obj)=0 from TABLE_NAME obj where obj.id = outerObject.id)
```

It is supposed to return boolean telling if the object is deleted in TABLE_NAME. It works great when running with H2, but fails with syntax error when running with DB2 9.7.0.4.

I have tried executing some similar bare sql queries on both databases and H2 executes all of them without problems, but I am not able to return boolean anyhow in DB2, for example

```
SELECT count(*)=0 from TABLE_NAME
```

fails with syntax error as well as

```
SELECT 1=0 from TABLE_NAME
```

IBM says that the boolean type was introduced in 9.7 but I am confused about usages. The page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053651.html says that

> The Boolean data type can only be referenced as: (...) Return type

But it also says

> The Boolean data type cannot be returned in a result set.

Is it possible to execute a boolean returning query in DB2 or do I have to return count(*) to Java and check if its zero on the Java side?

Comment: The `BOOLEAN` data type is only available in the SQL PL context (i.e. stored procedures, functions etc.) but not in SQL proper.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with exists query:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select obj from TABLE_NAME obj where obj.id = outerObject.id)
```

also the count(obj) value of 0 should be interpreted as false so you can simply negated

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately I wasn't using the subselect in subquery but I was returning its value as one of selected values - something like
select outerObject.name, (select obj from TABLE_NAME... ) from OuterObject outerObject

Answer (score 0):

You can create a udf (user defined function) that parses the boolean value and returns a string

```
Create function bool_to_char (boolean value) return char (5)
Begin
 Declare ret char (5) default 'false';
 If (value is true) then
  Set ret = 'true';
  End if;
  Return ret;
 End@
```

The you call the same select with the function

```
Select bool_to_char (xxx) from ....
```